# query class toggle to change span background image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, toggle, jquery-ui-accordion

Ok, I know enough about jQuery to get some of my tasks accomplished (well except this one apparently).

The situation:
I have an accordion menu that has plus and minus images that are shown in the left hand side of the menu. I want them to change when the child table is visible.

there is some bug in my code that won't allow this to happen.  it will change to the minus when you click one of the options and it will change to the plus when you click another option.

The Problem:
Once an area is expanded the accordion class won't change if you click the visible option again to collapse the element.

Here is a jsfiddle demo
http://jsfiddle.net/mKUNs/

Comment: the table is there for some ajax content that is loaded into it.

Comment: External stylesheets are fine, inline styles are okay, mixing both is very naughty.

Comment: Do you need previously opened box to hide?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/mKUNs/1/). **But don't use it.**

Your document is structured very badly. You've got tables with only one cell, and association between the header and the toggleable section is only by adjacency. You'd do better to change your markup so that each accordian is surrounded by a `<div>`/`<section>`.

Additionally, you're over using `id`s, and your CSS should all be taken out of the document. `align="center"` should **not** be used. Lastly, why muddle things by having a class for `expand`ed and `collapse`d? The two are mutually exclusive, so just use one class!

---

[This is how you should do it](http://jsfiddle.net/mKUNs/4/):

#### HTML

```
<div class='accordian'>
    <h3><span class='icon'></span>Option 1</h3>
    <div>
        the box should be black now, if you click this option
        again it should turn white
    </div>
</div>
<div class='accordian' id='weekly'>
    <h3><span class='icon'></span>Option 2</h3>
    <div>
        the box should be black now, if you click this option
        again it should turn white
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.accordian h3 {
    background-color:#689937;
    color:#fff;
    height:30px;
}
.accordian .icon {
    background-color:#fff;
    background-size:25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    padding-left:5px;
    float:left;
}
.accordian.collapsed .icon {
    background-color:#000;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.accordian').each(function() {
    var accordian = $(this);
    var header = accordian.find('h3');
    var content = accordian.find('div');

    header.click(function() {
        content.slideToggle('medium');
        accordian.toggleClass('collapsed');
    });

    content.hide();
    accordian.addClass('collapsed');
});
```

Comment: The tables were there so that three options could be displayed when the document was loaded and everything else would be hidden.  when the user clicks on one of those three options the embedded div area would become visible inside the table.

Comment: @peledies: But why a `table`?